# UK visa in NY (Indian Citizen)

Tags: visas, uk, new-york-city, consulates

I took all the steps as shown in the gov.uk link to [Apply for a UK visa in the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa).

1. Apply online
2. Paid fees
3. Go to your appointment
4. Post your application

For #4 I sent my application to following address via UPS but they returned it and UPS shows **"The receiver does not want the product and refused the delivery."**

> UK Visas and Immigration,
>   British Consulate General,
>   845 Third Avenue,
>   FL 10,
>   New York, 10022

What did I miss?

Comment: What link below? Did you mean this one? https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa

Comment: Did your posted application include your passport?

Comment: @choster not necessarily - with UPS the recipient does have the right to check the parcel and its contents prior to acceptance, and can refuse acceptance even after opening it.  Been there, done that.

Comment: @Moo Fair enough.

Comment: @Moo
Yes that's the link.
Yes, I included the passport.
UPS store from where we sent the application called and said that they received the package back.
I will find out if the package was opened after I collect the package from UPS later today.

Comment: @tejpratap did you include the return postage label (the site says for your documents, but Im not sure if that includes your passport - every time Ive got a visa from other countries, the issuing authority paid for return postage within the same country)?

Comment: @choster my UPS example is when someone shipped me an iMac G5 - it arrived boxed but the box was rattling, so with the driver stood there waiting for my signature, I opened the box, discovered nothing but bricks in there, and refused acceptance.  Driver took the box away again without any argument.

Comment: @Moo Yes, I included UPS return label with the application.
Just picked up the package from UPS.
It was definitely opened.
No sign/info/notification why delivery was refused.

Comment: I am planning to go to 845, 3rd Ave NY. I know they will not accept application by hand but if someone can tell why delivery was not taken that will be helpful. Do you guys know what floor they would be on...10?

Comment: @tejpratap its highly unlikely anyone will talk to you without an appointment, and unfortunately its highly unlikely that this question can be answered without actual information from the person who rejected the delivery :/

Comment: @Moo yeah I am aware of that. Just gonna try my luck tomorrow as I have to visit someone who is couple of blocks away from their location.

Comment: @Moo 
So I went to UK consulate.
Reception guy asked me all sort of questions (seemingly relevant).
He then called the consulate and gave them my details. (Name, DOB, GWF numbers)
Consulate guys replied that they returned the package as it was already open... bummer!
Now reception guy suggested (or insisted) that I should use UPS store around the corner.
So I went there and dispatched the package again to be delivered at 10:30AM tomm.
Let's see what happens now.
I also called previous UPS store and asked for refund after giving them the whole story from consulate.

Comment: @tejpratap Did everything work out? You should feel free to post and accept an answer to your own question, as the tip to use a particular UPS store location may be helpful to others.

Comment: Yes, basically it was the stupidity of UPS (twice). I got the UK visa in 4 days.

Answer (score 4):

As reported in the comments,

> I went to UK consulate. Reception guy asked me all sort of questions (seemingly relevant). He then called the consulate and gave them my details. (Name, DOB, GWF numbers) Consulate guys replied that they returned the package as it was already open... bummer! Now reception guy suggested (or insisted) that I should use UPS store around the corner. So I went there and dispatched the package again to be delivered at 10:30AM tomm.

So in the end, it seems like this was a fluke caused by UPS or someone else opening the package before delivery, causing it to be refused. Everything worked out after re-sending the materials, and the OP received the visa after 4 days.