# UK Visa Application Service Requires UPS Return Label

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

I have sent my passport to VFS Global, through FedEx. However, I just received an email that they only use UPS in the US, and thus I must arrange a UPS return courier service. However, having checked online and called customer service, I am not sure if I can do this... Unless I misunderstood something, you must have sent the package with UPS to use them for a return label, am I wrong?

Comment: Does it have to be done as a return, rather than as the new transaction it will be?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116499/how-to-send-the-uk-visa-application-in-the-usa?r=SearchResults

Comment: Did you actually include a shipping label with your package when you sent it in?

Comment: Yes I included a shipping label, but they require a UPS one