# UK Tourist Visa Issues limited time remaining

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

I am a permanent resident of the US. My family was supposed to travel to the UK for a holiday on May 13th 2019. My biometrics was scheduled for April 5th at my local application support center (Austin). Upon arriving there on that day I came to find out that the service was temporarily suspended.

I went to the premium application center in Houston for my biometrics on April 18th. I posted my biometrics slip, supporting documents and my passports with the application through UPS Express Service. The package was supposed to be delivered on Monday, April 22. However, I got a call from UPS saying that my package was refused by the New York Office.

The package was sent to the following address : 
VFS Services USA Inc 
UKVI ScanningHub
80 Broad St 
Fl 6
New York, NY 10004-2838

I don't understand why my package was refused. UPS doesn't give any explanation and says it's coming back to me. I am supposed to leave for the UK on May 13th 2019 for my 10 day trip. Does anyone know if purchasing a bronze package from VFS help expedite my visa process?

Comment: Similar: [UK visa in NY (Indian Citizen)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/108734/19400).  In that case, the package was refused because it had been opened before delivery.  If this is also the reason in your case, you can just resend the package.

Comment: Who would have opened it ?

Comment: it's impossible to know, and it doesn't particularly matter.  Most likely it was done by accident.

Comment: There is a limit of 5 days on the biometrics. Do you know if they consider that? I am thinking of applying through VFS as I have limited days (18 days) for travel. Do you know if buying a bronze package from VFS will expedite my process. I have emailed VFS twice but they havent replied.